# Invalidate IRibbonUI at MS Excel Startup

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, ribbon

I have created an Excel AddIn using C# VSTO. There are few ribbon buttons which are to be made available for the the selected users.

```
        private Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;
        private bool SuperUserEnabled= false;

        public Ribbon()
        {
        }
        public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
        {
            return GetResourceText("MyUtilities.Ribbon.xml");
        }


        public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
        {          
            this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
        }


        public void RibbonActions(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {          
            switch (control.Id)
            {
                case "Button1":
                    // some code
                    break;
                case "Button2":
                    //Some code
                     break;
             }
         }
```

The GetEnabled callback in xml file uses the below code to verify the user status.

```
        public bool CheckUserPrevilage(ref Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        //The idea is to validate only the first button. The rest are validated by virtue of the first button.
        if (control.Id == "Button1")
        {
            UserValidation UserStatus = new UserValidation();
            string UserPrevilage= UserStatus.GetUserPrevilage();

            if (UserPrevilage== "Super User")
            {
                SuperUserEnabled= true;
            }
        }
        return SuperUserEnabled; //SuperUserEnabled is a global variable
    }
```

Some users are given the permission as a super user after few months or the permission is taken back. The code need to check for the user privileges and invalidates the ribbon and enable or disable the ribbon.

When the user privilege is upgraded/downgraded, I am able to invalidate the ribbon with a button.

The problem I am facing now. It works in the debug/Release mode but not when the addIn is installed with the Click-once setup file.

In this case whatever is the installation status of the addin will remain forever. After the invalidation the buttons are enabled or disabled only for that session of the excel. If the excel is restarted, the buttons are taken from the original catch.

Is there a way to invalidate the ribbon at the start event of the excel.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to invalidate the ribbon at the start event of the excel.

You need to use the `IRibbonUI.Invalidate` or `IRibbonUI.InvalidateControl` methods for that. For each of the callbacks the add-in implements, the responses are cached. For example, if an add-in writer implements the getImage callback procedure for a button, the function is called once, the image loads, and then if the image needs to be updated, the cached image is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in-place until the add-in signals that the cached values are invalid by using the `Invalidate` method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached. The add-in can then force an immediate update of the UI by calling the `Refresh` method.

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: I have used `IRibbonUI.Invalidate` method in the button which invalidates all the buttons. But the problem here that the disabled or enabled buttons remain only for that session of excel. I don't want to redo clicking procedure for every excel session.

Comment: If you want to get your settings persisted you need to save them somewhere, for example, to a file on the disk. Next time when the Office application is started and ribbon callbacks are invoked you can read values and return appropriate values in the callbacks defined.

Comment: I only have bool condition which I am checking before the Invalidation therefore, I do not necessarily need to store the settings.

Comment: True. Where is the issue then?

Comment: The issue is that the Invalidation works only for open session of Excel. Once the Excel is restarted, the ribbon picks the old status of the buttons. This means the original ribbon which was at the time if installation is displayed. This is forcing me to Invalidate the ribbons for every new session of the excel.  Do you have any idea if we can trigger the ribbon invalidation at the Startup event of the addin?